# vim and .vimrc won't open after .vimrc modification. Need to force open

Tags: vim

How do I force open my .vimrc?

I recently made a modification, not certain exactly what I did, but I think I accidentally typed an "x" in my plugins when trying to close. Suddenly neither vim or .vimrc will open.

I get a pause, several blank lines, and then terminal just returns to default command line.

Comment: Rename your .vimrc file to something else, this way you will be able to start vim.  Edit your "something else" file, rename it .vimrc after to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vim -u NONE .vimrc` to skip reading all startup files and edit .vimrc.

Comment: Solved it! And super easy too! Can't thank you enough.